# r - getting all NA in ordered factor column

Tags: r, rstudio

Instead of showing more2 or less2 in the column, it only shows up as NA. Why aren't the character names appearing instead?

```
careermore2 <- vector(mode="character",length=length(mlb$careeryrs))
"less2" <- careermore2[mlb$careeryrs<=2]
"more2" <- careermore2[mlb$careeryrs>=2]
No.seasons <-       factor(careermore2,levels=c("more2","less2"),exclude=NA,ordered=TRUE)
mlb2 <- cbind(mlb,No.seasons)
str(mlb2$No.seasons)
head(mlb2$No.seasons)
mlb2[mlb2$No.seasons=="more2",]
```

Comment: remove the double quote in variable name

Comment: where does `mlb` come from?

Comment: @HubertL R doesn't care: `"foo" <- 99` and `foo <- 99` are equivalent. Weird eh? But not advised.

Comment: Thanks @Spacedman I wouldn't have guessed!!!

Comment: `careermore2 ` is initialized with empty strings ("")

Comment: mlb is the data.frame

Comment: @HubertL I'm not a programmer so I don't know what that means at all

Comment: @kacey yes, but unless we know what `mlb` is we can't reproduce your problem. As it is, I think I can reproduce it by making a simple data frame with one column. But its better if you can make a reproducible example by pointing to or creating the data in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at `careermore2` I would say you've got these the wrong way round:

```
"less2" <- careermore2[mlb$careeryrs<=2]
"more2" <- careermore2[mlb$careeryrs>=2]
```

That creates two objects. You really meant:

```
careermore2[mlb$careeryrs<=2] = "less2"
careermore2[mlb$careeryrs>=2] = "more2"
```

ie set the corresponding values in `careermore2`. And you probably want `<2` or `>2` rather than have `=` in both...